# Varios dominios en un mismo hosting (don web)

Tags: javascript, php, web, aplicación-web, hosting

Actualmente tengo varios dominios en un mismo hosting. El dominio principal dominio1.com accede a la web alojada en public_html/index.php el problema es al intentar que alguno de los otros dominios ingrese a una carpeta secundaria....
Pongo ejemplo de mi htacces actual

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio1\.com\.ar
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ dominio1/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio2\.com
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ dominio2.com/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Actualmente el primer dominio funciona bien pero el dominio2 me da error y no muestra nada...

Comment: Los otros dominios deben apuntar a la misma IP. Esto lo revisas desde el registrador como Godaddy u otros proveedores.

Comment: esto me parece que tiene que ver con configuración de servidores...

Comment: debes consultar esto https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Todos los dominios apuntan al servidor

Comment: Aparte del .htaccess tendrias que editar el archivo de configuración de apache y crear los <virtualhost> necesarios, o bien poner más alias al virtualhost de tu dominio para que interprete bien donde buscar esos subdominios